# How to Send and Receive SMS through application?

Tags: sms

In windows I want to make an application, which can send and receive and process sms. How it is possible? I am from India and this app will be used in India.

How can I receive sms in computer, I think through cellular GSM modem, It is possible to send and receive sms. Where can I find APIs to connect to modem to send and receive sms?

I am comfortable in Qt & MFC programming.

Thanks,
 Sunny.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a GSM modem which supports it, then you can send a set of AT commands to [send](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp) and [retrieve SMS from it](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToReceiveSMSUsingPC.asp).

If you are dealing with message in bulk, you'll probably want to sign up for an SMS gateway service instead. These usually provide an HTTP API and don't require a GSM modem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send/receive SMS using Modem then [this link](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=95&info=product-manual/developers-guide) might be helpful. If you want to have large scale capabilities to send/receive SMS then you can contact SMS Resellers like [Gateway4SMS](http://gateway4sms.com/resellers.php). Search google for more such providers. There are plenty of them in India.

Besides these technical things, you need to be aware that it is illegal to send bulk SMS from your mobile phone in India. You need to have 5 digit special codes (like 57575) or 11 character (TD-IRCTC) name to send bulk SMS which will be provided to you by bulk SMS resellers.

If you are thinking to contact service providers like Airtel or Vodafone to connect to their SMSC (SMS center) then be aware that Airtel has pulled out of this business because it is ethically not so right. Your only options are Vodafone/Tata teleservices but those guys don't respond to you if you are small time player.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by using a third party API. Some I know that work well are:

- restSms.me
- Twilio.com
- springedge.com
- Clickatell.com

I have used all of them and they easiest/cheapest one to implement was restSms.me

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get a modem that is capable to receive AT COMMANDS.

take a look at [this](http://www.developershome.com/sms/atCommandsIntro.asp) article.

I used the [following](http://cgi.ebay.com/Wireless-EDGE-GSM-GPRS-Modem-USB-Adapter-Earphone-Call-/200519181423?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2eafdfe46f#ht_3658wt_1168) modem, and it works perfectly.

Another way would be to use an SMS gateway such as [CLICKATELL](http://www.CLICKATELL.com) I use my own modem to receive messages, and their gateway for sending.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot send SMS through your modem.  There are third party SMS gateway services, but I'm uncertain of how well or if they work in India.

Start reading here [SMS Gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) and then you should be able to google for gateway services.

Comment: It is very much possible to send SMS through modem if that modem supports AT commands.

Comment: All telephone modems support AT commands.  I believe the Sunny was referring to a standard phone modem, not a Cellular modem. A standard POTS modem cannot send or receive SMS. A Cellular modem may be able to, but I doubt that is what he was referring to.

Comment: Mystere Man, I was referring to Cellular Modem. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: My appologies.  When someone just says "modem" it generally means a standard telephone modem.  That's why they have qualfieis like "Cellular Modem", "GSM Modem" or "Wireless Modem".  In reality, those aren't modems either, which is why they're called "Cellular Adapters" but that's just being picky.  You should edit your question to clarify, although by now you've probably received your answers anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this task, either to use AT commands for **GSM modem** or to use some gateway. Remember AT commands are not easy to handled, specially you feel difficult to handle incoming messages, 
Using GSM Modem, 
**GSM Modem with proper multi threading**
You can find a [library or exe](http://rapidsmsserver.com) here.
 This is i think a ready made product but you can ask them for free liscence or may be some notes to study how did they make it, its name is rapidsmsserver and it is very nicely made.

There is another way to build this, sending sms using HTTP protocol, but what you required is available in the link i made above.